# homemade coconut flavoured yogurt?

Tags: yogurt, coconut

I love there store bought coconut flavoured yogurts. I usually make my own but i cant find any type of coconut aromas around (even synthetics). Is there some way to do some similar yogurts?  I use powdered milk, whey and casein in my yogurts so the only missing ingredient is the aroma.

Comment: How difficult exactly is it for you to get coconut-flavored things? A lot of extracts can be ordered online, and then there's shredded/grated dried coconut, fresh coconut, coconut milk, and so on. You're not going to have much luck creating coconut flavor without coconut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two choices when flavoring yogurt: [while you are making it and after it is made](http://mryogurt.info/flavoring). If you want to make a batch of yogurt and choose your flavors later you may enjoy adding coconut extract (or other extracts) after the fact. However, if you are set on a single flavor (as your question implies) you will get better results adding a flavoring oil, the chemistry of oils vs. alcohol seem to react differently. Check out the "[Mr. Yogurt](http://mryogurt.info/flavoring)" link, he has done some experimenting that will help you along.

Answer (score 6):

Use coconut milk powder. It is very fine and dissolves easy and tastes great, better than artificial essence. Also it is pure white and does not alter the texture or color. I found it in an Indian store, what a find. I also use it in coconut custard pies dissolved in regular milk instead of the canned coconut milk, and to change basic cake recipes into coconut cake.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I've edited your answer (and your previous one) - we like to have things clearly written, so it's easier for everyone to read.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need a synthetic flavour? If not, why don't you simply add grated coconut or coconut milk to your yoghurt?

Comment: because usually the bacteria seems to make everything you put in the yogurt taste strange.

Comment: I've actually never tried to make coconut yoghurt, but have not had any problems at all with any other flavour I've added. BTW, why are you not simply using milk to make yoghurt instead of milkpowder, whey and casein? Perhaps the preprocessing of your ingredients cause some kind of "mismatch" with added flavours.

Comment: its not made just from powdered stuff, but it is added http://webs.hogent.be/~fboc691/artikel14.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I just made my first batch using the coconut flavoring from Spices Etc. https://www.spicesetc.com/product/Coconut-Flavoring/Natural-Flavorings

It is truly excellent. I used 1/2 TBSP in one quart of milk and it has great coconut flavor.

I recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make yogurt from coconut milk,I bet that tastes like coconut!

Comment: Very interesting option. I never knew that this is possible. Are these standard lactobacili you'd use for coconut milk yogurt, or specially bred cultures?

Comment: It does not work. It comes out smelling a little like coconut but tasting like a bad batch of plain yogurt. The recipe I followed called for 4 cups of canned coconut milk. I love coconut yogurt but the only store I could find it at quit selling it. It was Liberte brand & their Lemon yogurt is wonderful also. I was thinking of trying coconut cream, instead of milk. But I don't think this will work either. If anyone has an easy recipe for Coconut Yogurt (without having to use whole coconuts) please pass it along. It would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have been making homemade coconut yogurt in a "Cuisinart Electric Yogurt Maker" for at least 2 years now, and I simply love the way it tastes. Here's the way I make my yogurt:

- I warm 4 cups of my store bought, Pasteurized, homogenized, Vitamin D, Grade A milk, in the microwave about 3-3:30 minutes until it is only about 120 degrees.
- After heating I pour about 3/4 cup into a separate measuring cup.
- Once the temp. drops between 105-110, I then add 6oz. plain homogenized yogurt (that I bought from the store), and mix very well.
- Meanwhile, I have added about 2/3 - 3/4 C. of sugar, 3/4 C. instant powdered milk (for thickening), and 1 heaping TBS. of "McCormick Brand" Coconut extract to the other milk, & mix thoroughly.
- I check the temp. of this milk, if it's 105-110, I then add the other milk with the starter in it, mix thoroughly.
- At this time you could add shredded coconut (optional; as much as you would like).
- I then pour my mixture into the yogurt container in the machine. I set the time for 12 hours and it turns out wonderful!